# jquery ajax error when iterating through result set from asp.net mvc method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Calling an asp.net mvc3 controller method which returns the results fine (list of an object) and passes the list (c#) to the following jQuery Ajax function:

```
    //$("#yourtableid > tr").remove();
function getAnswers(qid) {
      var url = "/rankings/getanswers/" + qid;
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {qid: qid}, //"{}",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        var cars = response;
        $('#rankings').empty();
        var i = 0;
        debugger;
        $.each(cars, function(index, car) {
          $('#rankings').append(
           "<tr rorder=\"" + car.Ranking + "\"><td>" 
           + ++i.toString() + "</td><td align=\"left\"><span onclick=\"adjustRank('" 
           + car.Id + "')\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">" 
           + car.Text + "</span></td><td></td></tr>"
          );
        });
      },
      failure: function(msg) {
        $('#rankings').text(msg);
      }
    });
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this but I get the following error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result

Comment: one more suggestion use a single quote for you strings  & u dnt hv to worry abt escaping double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `++i.toString()` is invalid. What did you want to achieve? `(++i).toString()` ?

Comment: I'm such a dork... that was totally it. It was working before I added the toString() method lol. Total oversight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you convert the array to a json in your action code.. you could do it as follows:

new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(array);

also a suggestion to make this code readable and maintainable

```
var stringToAppend= $("<tr order=\"" + car.Ranking + "\"><td>")
.append($((++i).toString() + "</td><td align=\"left\"><span onclick=\"adjustRank('") 
.append( car.Id + "')\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\">") 
.append(car.Text + "</span></td><td></td></tr>")
```

and replace the double quotes with single quotes for the strnigs and dnt escape the double quotes

What this does it guarantees that your markup is well built else jquery will throw an error and the code is readable

Comment: No, didn't do it but the array can be read in the debugger and the elements are all there with the proper values... I suppose I could try JSON